# Global variables crashes program

Tags: ios, variables, global-variables

I've never used global variables, and and I get an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_serverName", referenced from:
      -[ANAdFetcher requestAdWithURL:] in ANAdFetcher.o
      -[AdSettingsTVC obtenerServidor:] in AdSettingsTVC.o
      -[ANAdFetcher requestAdWithURL:] in ANAdFetcher.o
      -[AdSettingsTVC obtenerServidor:] in AdSettingsTVC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The code:

```
<AdSettingTVC.h>

extern NSString *serverName;

<AdSettingsTVC.m>

- (IBAction)getServer:(UISegmentedControl *)sender{

    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        serverName = @"Servidor 1";
    } else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        serverName = @"Servidor 2";
    } else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
        serverName = @"Servidor 3";
    }
}

<AnAdFetcher.m>

self.URL = URL ? URL : [self adURLWithBaseURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", serverName]];
```

Comment: You might want to brush up on the distinction between a compiler error and a program crash.

Comment: There are probably a million better ways to solve this problem.  Delegate/protocol.  NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a *Linker* error. The linker is noting that your program is missing `_serverName`.

This is a **declaration**: `extern NSString *serverName;`

This is its **definition**: `NSString * serverName = nil;`

0) Chances are good a global is not a good idea here. Why not use an ivar?

1) Chances are a the variable may be `static`: `static NSString * serverName = nil; // << in your *.m`

2) If a global `extern` variable is what you need, you need to provide its definition someplace (unless you never reference it).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare it with *extern*, if you need a global variable. *extern* basically means you want to access a global variable defined in another file.

Use *static* instead of *extern* when you want a global variable to be accessible only within the *.m file where it's defined.

If you make a global variable without declaring it *static*, then you can not reuse the same name again in other *.m files for different variables (instead, you will need to always declare it with *extern* in other files).

Personally, I'd recommend refactoring to avoid the global variable. Or at the very least making it *static*. By allowing to modify values globally, you can make some bugs very hard to trace.